# Have to use the URL output into a GUI

Tags: javascript, iframe

I'm working on a web portal for my prod environment. The idea is to use URL's to hit the server and provide a GUI output.. I want to use the output of a URL and display red or green based on the result..

I want to convert the below `iframe` to a page that displays a color based on the result. This would be for numerous servers on a single webpage... Update if the `iframe` option is good?

```
<br><br>
<iframe src="http://servername:port/trafficcontrol/TrafficControlServlet" > </iframe>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var myWindow = window.open("http://servername:port/trafficcontrol/TrafficControlServlet", "_blank", "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=500,left=500,width=400,height=400")
}
</script>
```

Comment: A result? A result of what exactly?

Comment: Result of Traffic Control Servlet... Like Traffic_OFF or Traffic_ON..